# Start the pipeline only after approval and merge

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a problem that pipeline is starting immediately after the merge request and it does not wait for the approval and merge.

I want the pipeline to start or show the manual deploy option only after the user
clicks approve. Is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need Premium Tier for [Required Approvals](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/approvals/index.html).

With [Approval Rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/approvals/rules.html) you can configure that a Merge-Request needs Approvals before it can be merged and optionally which user should do the approving.

[image]

Comment: I do have that. But the question is can I trigger pipeline only after the merge request is approved. Currently it is triggering immediately after the merge request.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I am aware of this. My only doubt is pipeline is starting before it is being approved.Is it possible to start the pipeline only after it is approved

Comment: Ah sorry, I misread your question. I don't think this is easily possible as you would need to check for approval status in a rules clause in your pipeline, but I haven't seen any predefined variable for that. Maybe you could check the approval status via the gitlab api.

Comment: Thank you again. One last question? Can I not show Manual deploy option to approver. I do not want the approver and Deployer to be the same person.